How to edit a slam_toolbox map a posteriori
I use the slam_toolbox to build a map (generates a .posegraph, .data, etc), and I later load it with slam_toolbox again to localize on it.
Once the map is done, how can I edit it to eg. remove artifacts or add fake obstacles ? (With a classic .pgm of .png map, I would just edit it with any image software, but how can I do it with the .posegraph and .data outputs from slam_toolbox ?)

Occupancy grid maps are stored as .pgm PGM and metadata.yaml.
You can edit the .pgm easily with any image-editor, e.g. Paint on Windows or https://www.gnome.org on Linux.

Unfortunately the slam_toolbox does not use .pgm (or other image formats) maps in localization mode, but a pose graph. From that pose graph, it is able to publish an occupancy grid. But I'm looking for a way to edit this pose graph a posteriori
